# Check existence of files with a given extension in a directory

Tags: perl

I don't want to specify a file name, want to use only extension.

like

```
if(-e "./dir/*.c"){
}
```

I want to check if any .c file exist in ./dir directory. 
Is it possible ?
Since I am not getting the correct result, If someone knows any alternative or correct way to use this -e switch in this scenario, please help me.

Comment: That's not a switch, and the `-e` switch is the one used with one line programs. Which is something completely different. What you have there is the [file test unary operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may help:

```
my @list = <*.c>;

if (scalar @list == 0) {
  print "No .c File exist.";
} else {
  print "Existing C files are\n", join (", ", @list), "\n";
}
```

Instead of <strike>spawning a subshell by</strike> expanding the file list using glob `<*.c>` you can also use the `opendir`, `readdir` functions as follows:

```
opendir DIR, $path;
my @list = readdir DIR;
closedir (DIR);
my $flag = 0;

foreach $file (@list) {
  if ($file =~ m/^.*\.c$/i) {
    print "$file\n";
    $flag = 1;
  }
}

if ($flag == 0) {
  print "No .c file exists\n";
}
```

Where `$path` is a variable which indicates the path of the directory.

Comment: or, more tersely, `if ( scalar( () = <dir/*.c> ) )`

Comment: `<>` aka `glob` hasn't used a subshell for a very very long time

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module, which is a core module in Perl version 5. It is recursive, which may or may not be what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;   # for output only

my @found;
find(sub { /\.c$/i && push @found, $File::Find::name; }, 'dir');
print Dumper \@found;
```

`$File::Find::name` contains the full path for the file. The regex matches against the `$_` which contains the base file name. Note that the first argument to the `find()` subroutine is an anonymous sub, a code block.

If you want to check for empty output, using the array in scalar context returns its size. A zero (false) size means no matches were found.

```
if (@found) {
    print "Found files: @found\n";
} else { ...}
```